# C++ what happens when function returns vector<shared_ptr<>>?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, shared-ptr, move-semantics

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Test
{
public:
    Test() {}
    ~Test() { std::cerr << "Delete\n"; }
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Test>> makeList()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Test>> list;
    list.push_back(std::make_shared<Test>(Test()));

    return std::move(list);
}

int main(int argc ,char **argv)
{

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Test>> list;
    std::cerr << "Before\n";
    list = makeList();
    std::cerr << "After\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Which I compile with:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -o ptr ptr.cpp
```

The output is:

```
Before
Delete
After
Delete
```

My question is:  why is there an object being deleted in the `makeList` function? My assumption was that the `list` from the function would be moved into `list` from `main` and that therefore no object would be deleted/recreated in the process?

Can this be avoided (as obviously this code is not optimum)?

Comment: You create a temporary `Test` object with `Test()`. A copy of that is then made by `make_shared`, then the temporary is destroyed. You likely want `std::make_shared<Test>()`

Comment: `return std::move(list);` should be `return list;` for efficiency reasons.

Comment: ^^ This.  OP: If your compiler isn't warning you about this, perhaps time to get a better compiler (or turn the warnings on).   The `std::move()` here inhibits the return-value-optimisation.  Recent versions of clang can warn you about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 Changes:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Test>> makeList()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Test>> list;

    // make_shared does not need a copy of an object, just constructor arguments
    list.push_back(std::make_shared<Test>());

    // return std::move(list) will defeat RVO. Never do that.    
    return list;
}
```

So, the important part is :

```
    list.push_back(std::make_shared<Test>(Test()));
```

->

```
    list.push_back(std::make_shared<Test>());
```

Just for clarification because I had the same today, and I had trouble seeing the difference.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just tried the move because I thought forcing it would make a difference but I tried both options so in reality the problem comes from the fact that I create a temp object when I make the call to `make_shared`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
list.push_back(std::make_shared<Test>(Test()));
```

Here temporary is created with `Test()`. Then copy c-tor for `Test` is invoked and temporary is destroyed. It is the first destructor call.

The second destructor call appears in the end of the program when `list` is destroyed.

The right form to avoid temporary creation is:

```
list.push_back(std::make_shared<Test>());
```

Besides you shouldn't use `std::move` returning the value because compiler cannot apply *Return value optimisation* in such case.

Answer (score 2):

The line `list.push_back(std::make_shared<Test>(Test()));` makes a temporary `Test` and then moves it into the actual `Test` constructed by `std::make_shared<T>`. This temporary is then destroyed.

`std::make_shared<T>` requires the arguments to be used in construction of `T`. For a default constructed `T` simply provide no arguments.

The correct use, in this case, is this:

```
list.push_back(std::make_shared<Test>());
```